# Trying to delete certain files hangs indefinitely

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to delete some files on a Windows 10 PC, and I just... can't.

I have files in several subdirectories - they're rips from DVDs, using MakeMKV, and each DVD gets its own subdirectory; I've been moving the contents of each into the parent directory so I can process them further.

Certain of the files, though, refuse to be moved (or renamed, or deleted.) I should add at this point that I can copy them just fine, but anything that tries to do something to the original just hangs indefinitely. (I've got a DOS prompt that's been attempting to delete one of these files for around 24 hours now, with nothing outputted.) They're not read-only or system files or anything special like that - for example, I've got an issue with one directory where four files were ripped, and three of them are perfectly fine, but the fourth just won't go.

I've tried:

- rebooting and trying this afresh

No difference

- defragging and scanning the disk

Windows claimed that neither of these were needed, but I did them anyway. No change.

I've tried using File Explorer to delete them - it gets as far as the Calculating prompt, then does nothing; using a CMD prompt, as mentioned above, just hangs with no output to the screen.

As far as I can tell, there's nothing trying to access these files (and in any case, if there was, I'd be seeing an error about that, rather than just nothing.)

The disk is around 1 terabyte, with 400 gigs free; the files vary in size between 700 megs and 2 gigs.

I'll also add that it seems to be these specific files; I've ripped other files into the same directory since this started, and those have been just fine when it came time to delete them. I've also had issues in the past where renaming a file in file explorer can take a minute or so to complete; but that was generally for the first file in a given folder, and the remaining ones were renamed with no delays, so I wrote it off as One Of Those Things.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to other things I can look at?

Comment: Try restarting in Safe Mode (Option in MSCONFIG boot tab) and then delete the files that way. This normally works if they are not Windows required files.

Comment: @Jonh suggestion is very good.  If that doesn't work, I myself would (in a pinch only) boot from a Linux Live boot disk and try it from there.  If you can't do that.. :( ... you might try the windows process monitor and watch what windows is actually doing with all of that time ;)

Comment: Oh.. one more thing.  It sounds crazy but I have had luck deleting files from WSL1 that for some reason Windows wouldn't delete on it's own.  I have no reason why this worked.. but it did.

Comment: That is because WSL is somewhat like a different OS and accomplishes what @CMasMas and I suggested.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I've tried with the Ubuntu app, but that's also hanging. I can't see anything in Windows Process Monitor, either, just the `cmd` window.

Comment: @John - I'll give that a try tonight, since the PC needs to be running during work hours

Comment: @John - yep, Safe Mode did it. Do you have any idea why it needed that? (And if you want to post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it)

Comment: Thanks. I have posted an answer with the main reasons why Safe Mode works many times (not always, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting troublesome files can often be done in Safe Mode. There are other "Problem Delete" tools, but Safe Mode is good because it it starts with a simplified set of apps that allows Windows to delete successfully. There will not likely be any app running that claims ownership of the file and the restart into a simplified mode also helps.

Try restarting in Safe Mode (Option in MSCONFIG boot tab) and then delete the files that way.

This normally works if they are not Windows required files.